# Why/when do Pokemon run away?

Tags: pokemon-go

My journal says that **my Ponyta ran away**

So, I was wondering when and why does a Pokemon run away?

[image: Example]

Comment: Your Ponyta didn't run away, a wild Ponyta did.

Comment: CP plays a factor in the rate at which a Pokemon will flee. It has also been noted by others that higher rates at which a Pokemon will run away are a punishment for GPS Spoofing.

Comment: @Sean, if there is a GPS spoofing penalty, I think the same penalty may apply if you are for real moving quite fast IRL. When I am sitting on the train trying to catch a pokemon, they tend to run away much more frequently than if I am walking.

Comment: When you are sitting on the train, **you** (also?) tend to run away much more frequently than if you are walking.

Comment: @Alderath That's what I've seen. I've read reports on the Pokemon GO reddit about people being temporarily banned for gaining a huge distance in such a short space of time - I guess they can't really differentiate between the two.

Comment: @Sean So I need to make sure to turn the game off whenever I am on a train or I will get banned?

Comment: @Alderath I'm not too sure if i'm honest but I know there's a speed cap that a lot of people have mentioned on the Pokemon GO reddit page which implies that they've been banned for 'GPS spoofing' through moving too quickly.

Comment: there is a base catch and flee rate for each pokemon. the difference in level between you and the pokemon will modify the rates. ie: higher cp pokemon will be harder to catch AND will flee more often. google pokemon flee and catch rates for more info.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your own captured Pokémon will not run away. The only way to lose it is transferring it by accident. Your journal is showing an instance of a wild Ponyta fleeing from battle, which can happen randomly if you fail to capture it too many times, probably more commonly with stronger Pokémon.

A good way to ensure a capture is using better Pokéballs and Razz Berries, but keep in mind that capture attempts can still fail and Pokémon can still flee even when using those items.

Comment: "too long to capture" is that time based or number of attempts? Like if I sit there for 3 minutes before throwing my first ball is it more likely to run than if I had thrown one right away?

Comment: I have noticed that when on a bus, flee rates are higher.  I assume that is about moving out of range.

Comment: @DasBeasto once you enter the capture screen, the pokemon will stay there as long as your app is open. The only time pokemon will run is after an unsuccessful capture attempt. Each attempt has a separate chance of having the pokemon run

Comment: @JoeyHoang source?

Comment: clarification: source of `Each attempt has a separate chance of having the pokemon run`, please.

Answer (score 1):

The more CP a Pokémon has the harder it gets to catch it. That Ponyta had 400 CP, which is pretty hard to catch with a simple Pokéball. 
You'll have to use better Pokéballs and Berries in order to have a good chance of catching a high CP Pokémon.

(There is still no guarantee to actually catch one when using Berries and good Pokéballs, but it will increase the chance significantly.)

Answer (score 0):

Once a Pokemon is captured, it will never run. You can send it away to the professor, but it won't run on it's own.

While in battle, however, they can flee. 
Some Pokemon have a higher chance to flee naturally compared to others. 
The higher CP they have, the higher their chance as well.
The higher your level is, the higher their chance seems to also be. This could mean you are trying to get a 50cp pidgey and it may flee if you are level 20+ anyhow.
Last but not least, as others have said, if you are moving too fast.. it seems to increase the flee rate as well. This may simply be once you are out of the range of where they spawned while you still battle them that the flee may happen (or is increased in likelyhood).